# list marked files in dired in another buffer

Tags: dired

I want to list particular files in a buffer, with each file on its own line. I want to be able to choose the files to list from a Dired buffer.

I tried copying file names to the clipboard, and then pasting what I copied, but that puts all of the file names on the same line. For example if I mark these file nams

`Slide1.JPG
Slide2.JPG
Slide3.JPG`

issue `0w`

then paste and they are all in 1 line:

```
/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide1.JPG/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide2.JPG/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide3.JPG
```

I instead want each file to have its own line so it will look like this:

```
/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide1.JPG

/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide2.JPG

/home/zeltak/org/attach/bgu/courses/BGUC004.GIS.Planners/images/t2/Slide3.JPG
```

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it important for you to copy to the clipboard and then paste?

If you just want file names listed in a buffer then you can easily do that using [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

Just mark the files whose names you want to list, then hit **`C-M-l`**.

The files are listed in a buffer named `*Files*`, which you can of course rename.

(If you also mark some directories then they too are listed.)

**`C-h k C-M-l`** tells you:

> `C-M-l` runs the command diredp-list-marked, which is an interactive
>       compiled Lisp function in `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-M-l`, `menu-bar operate diredp-list-marked`.
>
> `(diredp-list-marked &optional ARG PREDICATE)`
>
> List the marked files in this Dired buffer.
>       A prefix arg specifies files to use instead of the marked files:
>
> - Numeric prefix arg `N`: The next `N` files (previous `-N`, if < 0).
> - `C-u C-u`: *All* files, but *no directories*.
> - `C-u C-u C-u`: *All* files and directories, *except* `.` and `..`
> - `C-u C-u C-u C-u`: *All* files and directories, *including* `.` and `..`
> - Any other prefix arg: The *current line*'s file only.
>
>   You can use `RET` or `mouse-2` to visit any of the files.
>     If `tooltip-mode` is on then moving the mouse over image-file names
>     shows image previews.
>
>   Non-interactively, non-nil arg `PREDICATE` is a file-name predicate.
>     List only the files for which it returns non-nil.

You can also do the same thing for all marked files *including those in marked subdirectories, defined recursively*.  You do that using **`M-+ C-M-l`** (command `diredp-list-marked-recursive`). (All commands that act on marked files defined recursively are on prefix key `M-+`.)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround using `xargs`:

- Yank the filenames as you did (all in 1 line)
- Select the line
- pipe to a command <kbd>C-u M-|</kbd>
- `xargs -n 1`

This will substitute your selection with one filename per line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`counsel`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), when you execute `find-file` or `projectile-find-file` and enter a regexp(or a search string) to narrow down the files to search, pressing <kbd>M-w</kbd> will copy the file names in as they appear in `ivy`.

But they don't copy the full path names of the files, only filename is copied OR if you are using `projectile`, the file names relative to the project root directory is copied. I'm not sure how you can get the full path name from `ivy`. But, if you're happy with just the file names, you can use this method :)

---

An alternative solution(this is better than the first solution) would be to use the command `directory-files` to get the file names. With this, you can also get the full path names of the file. Check help for the function using <kbd>C-h f</kbd> for more details.

Answer (score 0):

- Call `dired-do-shell-command` on the marked files, which is bound to `!` per default
- Enter `echo`, which is a shell command that returns whatever you feed it to `stdout`
- Observe a new buffer popping up with the output from `echo`, which contains all filenames separated by new lines.